# Is it possible to add C references to an objective c binding?

Tags: c#, objective-c, c, binding, xamarin.ios

There are some C style functions in an Objective C library I'm binding to that I need access to in my application. Is it possible to add these into the bindings in any way so I can access them in my C# application?

EXAMPLE from Cocos2d:

```
void ccGLActiveTexture( GLenum textureEnum )
{
#if CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE
    NSCAssert1( (textureEnum - GL_TEXTURE0) < kCCMaxActiveTexture, @"cocos2d ERROR: Increase kCCMaxActiveTexture to %d!", (textureEnum-GL_TEXTURE0) );
    if( (textureEnum - GL_TEXTURE0) != _ccCurrentActiveTexture ) {
        _ccCurrentActiveTexture = (textureEnum - GL_TEXTURE0);
        glActiveTexture( textureEnum );
    }
#else
    glActiveTexture( textureEnum );
#endif
}
```

EDIT

Link to header with functions I'm trying to import:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/cc_g_l_state_cache_8h_source.html

I tried this in my Extras.cs

```
public partial class CCGLProgram {
[DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern void ccGLUseProgram( uint program );

    public static void CCGLUseProgram(uint test)
    {
        ccGLUseProgram(test);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an entry point not found error. I guess my first thought is maybe the function is mangled but I thought since the 'extern C' is there that shouldn't be happening? Can anyone help me?

Comment: like what? show an example of "C style functions in an Objective C"

Comment: You mean the GLenum type or the function itself?

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code as DLL and make any function you want to call from C# as an EXPORT in your DLL? I don't get your exact question here. If you just want to call a function from C# which is coded in C++, you have to compile that as DLL, make exports and call exported functions from C#.

Comment: I'm using the objective c bindings for Cocos2d from here https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings . However, it doesn't include all the functions I needed so I've been adding to the ApiDefinition. Its easy for me to add Objective C classes/functions, but Cocos2d also includes important C Functions like the one you see above. I don't know how to add this to the ApiDefinition, or if its even possible. I just curious whats the best way to add this to the binding so I can reference the above C function from my C# project that includes the cocos2d dll. (And I do have a DLL)

Comment: what's your c++ compiler? do you use any IDE?

Comment: You have to open your c++ project, find how it exports functions, like EXPORT def file or inline EXPORTing, then add any function you want to use in C#. Where is original C++ project in github?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helps so I can point you to a better solution than `--nosymbolstrip`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add *classic* .NET **p/invokes**, `[DllImport]`, for any additional C API you need. They can be added to your binding assembly easily as doing bindings is a **two** step process.

First your API definitions (interfaces) are compiled, along with extra definitions (e.g. `enums`) into a temporary assembly.

Next that assembly is then used to generate code (using `btouch`): the bindings you'll use. It's possible to include more code, like the **p/invokes**, at that stage so they will be part of your final, compiled, binding assembly.

*Trick: There's a lot of samples available in GIT's [monotouch-bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings), just grep around for `DllImport` and you'll find some.*

**EDIT (2013-01-08)**

There's something wrong with the **Release** build (even if it simply calls `xcodebuild`) done by the Makefile since it works when I rebuild `libcocos2d.a` in debug. E.g.

```
cd monotouch-bindings/cocos2d/binding
make debug
```

To test this I added your code (a bit simplified) into the existing `extra.cs`:

```
public partial class CCGLProgram {
    [DllImport ("__Internal", EntryPoint="ccGLUseProgram")]
    public static extern void UseProgram (uint program);
}
```

and added a call to `CCGLProgram.UseProgram (0);` from inside the `FinishedLaunching` method of the Jumpy demo app.

**EDIT (2013-01-12)**

The debug and release builds are quite similar (not surprising). The **debug** build has a few debug related defines (again not surprising). OTOH the **release** build is done with `-fvisibility=hidden` which (I need to validate this later) sounds like a good candidate for this issue.

It's indeed a (non default, see last column) build setting in the Xcode project. Changing this settings to **No** (which is normally the default) will produce a **Release** build where you can use *normal* `[DllImport]` (like above) to call the C functions. Mystery solved :-)

[image: Xcode settings]

**EDIT (2013-01-13)**

This [change is now](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/commit/336e84c3a5be77c70e362d447622ee52f3632c99) handled in MonoTouch's bindings Makefile, i.e. rebulding your Cocos2d.dll assembly (do both a `make clean` and `make clean all` to remove the managed and native code) will solve this automagically. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks again poupou. I eventually last night found out about using DllImport, but I couldn't get it to work, but I didn't know where to put it. (I first tried putting it in Extras, and then again in my actual C# project) I'll check the samples and see if I can find an example that can help me.

Comment: I searched that github couldn't find Dllimport : repo:mono/monotouch-bindings Dllimport

Comment: @AwDogsGo2Heaven I see several of them by doing a `grep -r DllImport .`. E.g. `./RedLaser/binding/extra.cs` has some.

Comment: ah okay, I was using git hub's search function

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work, I get Entry point can not be found error.

Comment: You're on the right track, source wise, but maybe not build-wise. Now you need to verify that **(a)** you're correctly linking the static library with your application, e.g. mismatched architecture, and **(b)** that the symbol exists in the static library you have, e.g. it's documented to be in coco2d 2.0+ so earlier versions won't have that symbol (and that will get you an exception).

Comment: I got the Cocos2d bindings from the monotouch-bindings, the same one from the link you provided. then I ran the make file included in it, it downloaded the source code and created 3 libraries and a dll. I added a reference to that DLL in my application. I verified the above file is in the source code it downloaded. I'm not sure how to verify 'a' though.

Comment: I guess this is the Linking info: [assembly: LinkWith ("libcocos2d.a",LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "OpenGLES CoreGraphics QuartzCore")]

Comment: Opening the Library i see references to ccGLUseProgram and the others in there in several places...

Comment: If you're talking about the **native** library then it *only* covers **(b)** (the symbol exists) but not **(a)** (the static library is correctly linked). Check your build log (from MonoDevelop's error pad) after adding `v -v -v` to your **Additional mtouch arguments** (Project's Options) to get the maximum verbosity. Look for any (native) linker warning. Also make sure you're able to call into other coco2d (objective-c) code thru your bindings.

Comment: I'm away from my computer ATM but I'll try when I get home. And I have had no problem calling objective c code from the library.

Comment: Make debug does work, but I can't find anything about why it would work in debug and not release. =(

Comment: I have not *yet* compared the (release / debug) build logs - but all it takes is a single, misconfigured macro and everything (or a single thing) can get broken.

Comment: when you say build/release logs you mean the output generated when running the make files right? I did some quick comparisons of those last night but couldn't find anything that gave me any leads. I also can't find any resources about differences between release and debug builds and not being able to find an entry point. Tricky stuff =(

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I hope if anyone else has similar problems in the future this answer helps them. It took me a while to get back to this question because I've been busy, but now I can move forward on my project, so thanks again Poupou!

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, you mention that it works on Debug but not on Release. This might be happening because symbol its being "Stripped" by mtouch.

In order to test this please on the Project that is actually referencing your binding project add `--nosymbolstrip` to Release Configuration and give it a Try.

This does have an effect on the application final size, but at least you will know that is the problem and we can workout a workaround, will blog post about it.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Hope this helps.

Alex

Comment: It was a good guess. Sadly the MonoTouch project I used was **Debug** in both cases (so `mtouch` never stripped anything). What works is `cocos2d.a` *debug* build (from xcode) while the *release* build is missing some symbols. I *could* be MT related (can't think how) but there's definitively something different in xcode builds (correct or not - but different).

Comment: ahh so it is in xcode side, is the project available on Git?? I mean is the latest Cocos2d xcode project that you guys are using??

Comment: The Makefile downloads (uncompress and build from) the source tarball for 2.0